# What is the output of this method?

Tags: recursion

What is the output of this recursive algorithm per the input?

Input:

```
quest(7)
```

Code:

```
public static int quest(int a) {
    if (a <= 1) 
    return 
    } else 
    if (a % 2 == 0) 
    return a - quest(a - 1);
    } else {
    return a + quest(a - 1);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have tried to write this down on a piece of paper?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming 
`if (a <= 1) 
    return 
    }`

to be

`if (a <= 1) 
    return 1
    }`

For 7 as input, 
The result of 7+6-5+4-3+2-1is the output.

For 8 as input,
The result of 8-7+6-5+4-3+2-1is the output